# How can I possibly send this struct over network?

Tags: c, sockets, serialization

I've got the following struct:

```
struct fetch_info_t {
    u_int8_t grocery_type;
    u_int8_t arg[1024];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I'd like to send this over a socket to a server, to request data. I'd very much like to avoid any libraries, such as `protobuf`.
`grocery_type` can be any value between 1 and 255. Some grocery types, say type `128`, must provide additional information. I'ts not enough to provide type `128`, I'd also like to provide `Cheeses` as  a string. Having that said, type `129` must provide a number, `u_int32_t` and not a string, unlike `128`.

Basically I've allocated 1024 bytes for the additional information the system may require. The question is, how do I send it over a socket, **or more specifically, populate `arg` with the right information non-system-dependant**? I know `htonl` on the number could be used, but how do I actually set the buffer value to that?

I'd imagine that the info sending would actually eventually be casting the struct pointer to unsigned char array and send it like that over a socket. Let me please know if there's a better way.

Comment: just use `memcpy` to put the data into your buffer, and you can do the same on the otherside to pull it out.

Comment: For sending struct data using socket, you have to serialize and deserialize this struct (as you said, we can using char array

Comment: @ChristianGibbons How can I memcpy a `u_int32_t` (say 4 byte long) info a 1024-byte long `u_int8_t` array? What casting should be made?

Comment: Put it wherever you want, as long as you're consistent.  Makes most sense to put it at the start: `memcpy(dest.arg, &src, sizeof(u_int32_t));`. If you had multiple pieces of data you needed to transmit, you can store them all in there at different locations. (assuming `dest` is a var of your struct type, and `src` is a `u_int32_t` you wish to copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign directly the 32-bit value to the array
because the correct alignment is not guaranteed.
`memcpy()` will just replicate the bytes with not alignment problem.

```
u_int32_t the_value=htonl( ... );
struct fetch_info_t the_info;
the_info.grocery_type=129;
memcpy(the_info.arg, &the_value, sizeof(the_value));
```

Then, because your structure is packed, you can send it with

```
send(my_socket, &the_info,
     sizeof(the_info.grocery_type)+sizeof(the_value), 0);
```

In case you need to send a string

```
char *the_text= ... ;
size_t the_size=strlen(the_text)+1;
struct fetch_info_t the_info;
the_info.grocery_type=128;
memcpy(the_info.arg, the_text, the_size);
send(my_socket, &the_info,
     sizeof(the_info.grocery_type)+the_size, 0);
```

Note that the `'\0'` is transmitted here.

Comment: How `the_text` is `u_int32_t`?
Also when using `send` I could `sizeof(fetch_info_t)`, it should suffice?

Comment: @Xavier1FX yes, mybad, I just changed it before seeing your comment ;^)

Comment: @Xavier1FX It is possible to systematically send ``sizeof(fetch_info_t)`` bytes but in many cases most of these bytes will contain no relevant information (for example 1025 bytes transmitted where 5 would have been enough). I don't know if this is a problem in your application.

Comment: @Xavier1FX  But yes, it is much simpler to always expect the same length when receiving.

Comment: Thank you for the answer